# Apache httpd 2.2.22 not starting on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server

Running Windows 7 and just downloaded the 2.2.22 win32 x86 (no SSL) MSI installer and used all the defaults. It installed httpd under an `Apache Software Foundation` directory inside `Program Files`. When I go to my Start Menu and go to Start the Apache Server, I get this message:

[image]

Not sure what this means or what I need to do! I used the Typical/recommended installation and haven't messed around with any config files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite a delayed reply, but this may help others having the same issue.

I had this same type of error pop up when I was configuring an application to listen on port 443. As a result my Apache had to be configured to listen on port 443.

It could not bind to socket 443 due to it already being bound to by another application. I found that Skype and LogMeIn both bind on 443 and will block Apache from starting and listening on 443.

Shutting down these services and starting Apache made it work. If I were you I would use the `netstat` command and look at what is bound to port 80. If you have an application taking up a port 80 bind that you do not need, shut down the service for that application.

`netstat -b` did the trick (to view binds). Make sure you run the command prompt as Administrator.

**Another Note:** I am surprised it will not bind to 80. Being the common port for http, I thought this port could be bound to by many applications. Regardless, it is worth a try if you are still experiencing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You Could Use the xampp Control panel for windows, its consist of all the basic software bundles you need, right from apache, php, ftp and so on

Link : http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

After installing the Xampp control panel make sure that you run the application and start all of its servcies

Comment: Can you describe the linked content, and how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the link becomes invalid.  In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature--they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise.  See the [FAQ#promotion] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: Apache is trying to listen on port 80 (the web/HTTP port), but **it is already occupied**.

What you need to do is to figure out what program is running a webserver on your system and shut it down so that Apache can use it.

You can also configure Apache to use a different port (e.g., 8080, etc.) instead of 80; that way both programs can run, but there are a couple of issues with that:

- Users would need to specifically set the port of their browser to the custom port to connect to your Apache server
- If you are not aware of the existing webserver, then either you installed something a while ago and forgot about it (and presumably don't want it anymore), or worse, **it is malware** and you definitely want to remove it

The easiest way to find out what is listening on port 80 (or any other port for that matter), is to use [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx):

- Download and run the program(s)
- Sort on the *State* column
- Look for the entry on port `80`/`HTTP`
- Double-click the entry/entries that are listening on the port
- Look at the *(Process) Path* field to see what program is running

Of course this presumes it is a legitimate program or simple malware. If it is a rootkit, then it may be hidden and you will need to run some security programs to root it out (no pun intended).